# Change React Component Cause Wrong Position

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

We have a multi-layer structure, basically can be described as:

Component -> Page -> HOC

When props change in the page, the page will render different Component, something like this:

```
class Component ....
...

render() {
        switch (this.props.requestReducer.currentAction) {
            case NEW_BOOKING:
                node = <CustomerForm />;
                break;
            case SEA_EXPORT:
                node = <SeaExportForm />;
                break;    
            default:
                node = <BookingList />;
                break;
        }

        return(
            <div className="container">
                <Head>
                    <title>Booking</title>
                </Head>           
                { node }
            </div>                
        )
}

export default connect(state => state, { afterFetch })(menuWrapper(authWrapper(BookingPage)));
```

And then we have two HOC, responsible for auth check and Header Menu Generation tasks etc.

Then we meet a problem, when we switch the props, the component can be rendered correctly, but not in a right position. Say if the original component is longer than one page screen, and the second component is also longer than one screen as well, then the second screen will show from the middle part, not from the top as expected. Seems the switch will remember the position from the last component, and seems it will also skip the margin which defined within the menuWrapper HOC.

Is there any body meet the problem same as me?

Comment: a good idea is to always add a wrapping element (like <div>) around your dynamic Component. Why its "rendering lower than" depends on the css you are applying to your dynamic Component. CSS props like position:fixed, position:sticky can be positioned wrong.

Comment: Thanks @japrescott . Basically I found that when react rendering the component, it use the previous component bottom line as the same bottom line for the new component, so it causes the wrong position. Right now I'm just using a scroll to top for a tentative solution.